# Perl array filtering on string

Tags: perl, dns

I am trying to filter an array that gets a lot of information about DNS records on a BIND9 based DNS server. The ouput looks something like this:

```
print Dumper(@host_objs);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
'internal_updates_view' => bless( {
'use_nxdomain_redirect_Addresses' => 0,
'match_destinations' => [],
'zone' => test.tld,
'name' => test.test.tld,
*etcetera*
```

How can I make `print Dumper(@host_objs);` only the lines that contain 'name'?

Comment: The *et cetera* is the interesting part. Please show a hundred or so lines. Nothing will blow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your `@host_objs` are objects that are instances of the same class, you can call the `name` method:

```
foreach my $obj(@host_objs) {
   print $obj->{internal_updates_view}->{name}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can't find it on cpan, https://ipam.illinois.edu/api/doc/Infoblox/DHCP/View.html#name___

Comment: All the positions in the array are demarked by $VAR1, $VAR2, etcetera. They aren't all instances of the same class I think. At least, the solution didn't work for me.

Comment: you can print the class name of the $obj with: print ref($obj), "\n". Also, when print the Dumper, use references: print Dumper(\@host_objs), "\n"; I have updated my answer

Comment: perl 5.10 and later have the useful function `say`, which prints out stuff and adds a carriage return to it. You can enable by putting `use feature ':5.10'` or `use feature 'say'`. Then you can do `say Dumper(\@host_objs);`.

Comment: You are not using the `name` methd. You are accessing the object's internals by grabbing it's `{name}` key.